# Finding integers that do not appear on list

Tags: list-manipulation, import, filtering

Let's say I imported a large list of numbers into Mathematica, and found the min value and max value. In that range [min,max], how do I find all integers that do not appear in this list?

```
data = Flatten[Import["file.txt", "Table"]];
M = Max[data]
m = Min[data]
```

Using

```
newdata = DeleteDuplicates [data];
Sort[newdata]
```

I get this:

The range of values are

{19,20,22,..., 126, 128}

So I can tell that 21, for example, is missing

Comment: I'm totally missing your logic here. How exactly can a list have elements larger than its maximum?

Comment: I apologize, I specifically put the range, I'm trying to figure out how to put an output that specifically takes values that are missing in the range

Comment: To clarify: you want to get the members of `Range[Max[data]]` that are not present in `data`? Have you seen `Complement[]`?

Comment: I've heard of it, but I forgot what it was used for. I search on it in Wolfram and it's a pretty basic tool to find what is missing in a range of values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Complement[Range[m, M], data]

(*   {21, 24, 121, 124, 125, 127}   *)
```

Comment: Also: `Complement[Range @@ MinMax[data], data]`